# Как можно отключить авторизацию на странице Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-webforms

У меня есть Web - сервер, на который с помощью клиента на android пользователи заносят свои данные. Я сделал авторизацию для этого web - сервера и естественно теперь нельзя внести с клиента данные без авторизации. Вопрос: Как можно отключить авторизацию на странице Api, либо на контроллере(?). Или как - то можно авторизовываться при отправке данных с клиента? Авторизацию я делал с помощью веб форм:

```
 <system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms 
      loginUrl="MyLogin"
      timeout="20"
       defaultUrl="Default.aspx" 
         path="/" > 
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
      <user name="Vladimir" password="password" />  
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Код на кнопке при авторизации на веб -сервере:

```
 protected void LoginAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Validate();
        if (!Page.IsValid) return;

        if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(UsernameText.Text, PasswordText.Text))
        {

            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UsernameText.Text, false);
        }
        else
        {

            LegendStatus.Text = "Вы неправильно ввели имя пользователя или пароль!";
        }
    }
```

Вот так я отправляю данные с клиента(может как-то еще с ним можно данные для авторизации отправлять?):

```
 var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("Адрес моего веб- сервера/api/User");
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonData);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;



            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                stream.Close();
            }
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: [AllowAnonymous](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.allowanonymousattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: И ее на страницу контроллера вставить? Просто я пробовал, не помогло:(

Comment: Если вы используете asp.net web api контроллер, то вам надо указать этот аттрибут для всего контроллера или для тех действий, для которых анонимный доступ разрешен

Comment: Вот я вроде пробовал(приду домой попробую еще), но почему то не получалось, может это из-за того, что у меня автроизация сделана с помощью веб форм?

Comment: возможно связано с этим `<deny users="?"/>`, так как это по идее запрещает анонимный доступ

Comment: Да, запрещает..